# No Wrap but long words into next line

Tags: css, whitespace, word-wrap

I'm playing around with word-wrap and white-space for a while now, but I cant get this to work. I want no word separation in my headings, so long words should just be put into the next line. To clearify this, if the container is too small, I dont want it to behave this way:

```
A veeeeeeeeeeeeeeee-
eeeeery long heading
```

I want it to be that way:

```
A
veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery
long heading
```

This is my markup:

```
<header>
    <h3>Some random blog heading</a></h3>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
article h3{
width:200px;
word-wrap:normal;
word-break: normal;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I think I tried every possible combination, but it didnt do what I want. I cant imagine that it isnt possible.

Comment: where is your example?

Comment: do you have an example for what you currently have and something to demonstrate what you want?

Comment: *"long words should just be put into the next line"* this is the default behavior, AFAIK

Comment: by word-break: normal; that is default in css

Comment: If it is the default behaviour, my starter theme changes it. Of course I tried word-break:normal and it seperates the word.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: The current Firefox version.

Comment: Then I would recommend you install a debugger like Firebug, and find out exactly what CSS classes are being applied to your text, so you can reverse them.

Answer (score 0):

If you currently see a word divided in two lines as in your first example and you don’t want that, you just have to locate the thing that causes the word division. This can be CSS hyphenation with the `hyphen` property, or it may be caused by the SOFT HYPHEN character (possibly inserted via scripting), or even a common hyphen character “-” in the word – most browsers treat it as allowing a line break after it.

If you need help with the analysis, I think you need to reveal some of the actual content and markup and perhaps styling and scripting.

Comment: There are no such characters. Im talking about word breaking in case that the containers too small.

Comment: Words don’t just break by themselves. Please provide relevant information, preferably a self-contained document that demonstrates the issue. Or at least a URL of the actual page.

Comment: I know, that they dont break by themselves, but it seems to me in case that they a re too long for the container, there are only the options to break them or to let them overflow the container. I want them whole word to be in the next line. I will build a fiddle tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

```
Apply css on it

<div style="word-wrap:break-all;">A veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery long heading</div>

or

<div style="word-wrap:break-word;">A veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery long heading</div>
```

Comment: They both break words at arb itrary points. The question is obscure, but “no wrap” apparently means that words should not be broken at all.